# How to calculate the "Bounds" of the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to know, how to calculate the "Bound numbers" of the Mandelbrot set. So I mean the last number c that can be substitutet in
$ z, z^{2} + c, \left( z^{2} + c \right)^{2} + c, \left( \left( z^{2} + c \right)^{2} + c \right)^{2} + c, \dots $
before the series diverges.
How to calculate that?

Comment: What do you mean with 'last number '? The complex numbers do not have a (canonical) ordering.

Comment: It is known (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) that $-2$ is in the Mandelbrot set, and any number of modulus $>2$ is outside. Is that what you are looking for?